# Find Max date without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, max

I have simple database. What I want.

Get all employees who

1. over 50 years
2. participate in the development of 10 products
   and more

Also

The result should contain

1. Age of the employee
2. the employee's name
3. the last name of the product (for ProductEmployee.Date date)

[image]

I wrote this simple query:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Age, p.Name
    FROM ProductEmployee pe1
    JOIN Employee e
        ON e.ID = pe1.EmployeeID
    JOIN ProductEmployee pe2
        ON pe2.EmployeeID = e.ID
    JOIN (
        SELECT pe3.EmployeeID, Max(pe3.Date) Date 
            FROM ProductEmployee pe3
            GROUP BY pe3.EmployeeID
    )y ON(y.Date = pe1.Date)    
    JOIN Product p
        ON p.ID = pe1.ProductID
    WHERE e.Age > 50
    GROUP BY pe1.EmployeeID, e.Name, e.Age, p.Name
HAVING Count(DISTINCT pe2.ProductID) > 10
ORDER BY e.Name
```

But I have a question. Can this write without a subquery? In one sentence.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: You wrote this simple query?

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? There will be a different answer for MySQL/Postgres/Oracle/SQL-Server as each one of them supports different analytic functions and SQL features.

Comment: Yes. In two variants. Other variant with using (WITH).  But it also contains subquery. It is impossible to get rid of them...!
I'm using MS SQL 2008 (T-SQL). It's screenshot of fake database, but the structure is similar to it.

Comment: You can use a correlated sub-query for the date, but it will still be a sub-query. Correlated sub-queries are usually considered worse

Comment: It's works pretty fast. But I'm confused by this moment: `ON(y.Date = pe1.Date)` I have no index on this field.

Comment: Technically, what you have there is an inline view (or a derived table). You may get a minus point at an interview when you get a really pedantic interviewer if you confuse these terms

Answer (score 1):

Considering your sample table structure, use the below query it will give you expected output

I have used row_number which will remove the need of subquery

```
declare @employee table (id int, name varchar(10),age int);

insert into @employee values (1,'A',50);

insert into @employee values (2,'B',40);

insert into @employee values (3,'C',40);

insert into @employee values (4,'D',60);

declare @product table (id int, name varchar(10));

insert into @product values (1,'P1');

insert into @product values (2,'P2');

insert into @product values (3,'P3');

insert into @product values (4,'P4');


declare @productemployee table (EmployeeID int, ProductID int,[Date] date);

insert into @productemployee values (1,1,'1/30/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (1,2,'1/16/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (2,1,'1/28/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (2,2,'1/30/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (3,2,'1/29/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (3,3,'1/28/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (4,1,'1/28/2017');

insert into @productemployee values (4,3,'1/31/2017');
```

```
select t.name,age,t1.name as product_name from (select e.name,e.age,pe.ProductID,pe.Date,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ProductID order by date desc) as row_no from @employee e join @productemployee pe 
on e.id = pe.EmployeeID 
join @product p on pe.ProductID = p.id) as t
join
(
select p.id,p.name,count(pe.ProductID) cnt from @productemployee pe
JOIN @product p
        ON p.ID = pe.ProductID
    GROUP BY p.id,p.name
    ) as t1 on t.ProductID = t1.id
WHERE t.Age >= 50 and row_no=1 and t1.cnt >=10
order by t.name
```

Comment: i have executed your and my query against my sample data and i was getting same result. can you please provide your sample data if possible then i can modify query and generate expected results.

Comment: i create sample data from SQL Data Generator, over 1million records in every table. I found that your query returns dublicates.

Comment: ok can you send me some of your sample data so i can correct the query and remove duplicate records

Comment: you can download [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gstzsuz1xdi4k85/test.bak?dl=0) but it is 75MB

Comment: I tested again. Your query works like mine. I changed  > 10 to >= 10 but leave e.Age > 50. In your variant >=50

Comment: yes great that actually query i tested with my sample data so needed some modifications in where ....
i have downloaded your sample and will test against yours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134460/discussion-between-chintan-udeshi-and-seva).

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this:

```
select f1.Name, f1.Age, f4.LastProductName from Employee f1
cross apply 
(
    select top 1 f2.Name as LastProductName, count(distinct f3.productID) over(partition by f3.EmployeeID) NbProduct 
    from Product f2 inner join ProductEmployee f3 on f2.ID=f3.ProductID
    where f3.EmployeeID=f1.ID
    order by f3.Date desc
) f4
where f1.Age>50 and f4.NbProduct>=10
```

Comment: It is works if remove DISTINCT from count(distinct f3.productID). But the result is different from mine. Now I think where is bug)